# python passing variables between functions

Tags: python, variables, parameter-passing

I am trying to pass an integer to a function. I think it might not be working because I am calling it to many times? For example I create a 2d matrix in one function called Alist and then return it. With a second function I pass Alist and specify a location for the value I want from Alist which I then return. Finally (so far), a third function will ask for the returned value and Alist. Alist is printing fine but the returned value (node) is printing 0 when it should be 4. I guess that it is using the node = 0 variable declared at the top of the code but I am not sure why.

The first line of network.txt looks like this:
0,2,4,1,6,0,

```
Alist = []
node = 0

file = ("F:/media/KINGSTON/Networking/network.txt")

def create_matrix(file):
    with open('network.txt') as f:
        Alist = []
        for line in f:
            part = []
            for x in line.split(','):
                part.append(int(x))
            Alist.append(part)
    return Alist

def start_node(Alist):
        node = Alist[0][2]
        print (node)
        return node

#test neighbours to see if they can be used
def check_neighbours(node, Alist):
        print (Alist)
        print (node)
        #check for neighbours. if we start at [0][0] we must look for [0][1]
        #and [1][0]. Figure out how to add 1 to each cell to navigate across.

#running of code begins here
Alist = create_matrix(file)
start_node(Alist)
check_neighbours(node, Alist)
```

Comment: You need to show us the code that calls these functions. The ideal question is a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)—something we can run, against your input, and see how the output is different from the expected output.

Comment: Meanwhile, it's pretty confusing to have global variables, function parameters, and local variables all with the same name, and it's a red flag that you're expecting some kind of magic in the code we aren't seeing. For example, the `node` that gets set in `start_node` isn't the global. It _is_ getting returned, but unless the caller is doing something like `node = start_node(Alist)` to set the global, the global isn't going to change, so the value will still be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your problem, on the second line of "running of code begins here":

```
Alist = create_matrix(file) 
start_node(Alist) 
check_neighbours(node, Alist)
```

When you call `start_node(Alist)`, it creates a local variable (which happens to be called `node`) and returns its value, which you just ignore. This means the global variable `node` (despite the coincidental name) is not being changed, so it's still 0.

To make this work, you need to do the same thing you do on the line above:

```
node = start_node(Alist)
```

---

However, to make your code less confusing, you really should do a few things:

First, remove the `Alist = []` and `node = 0` at the top. Defining them before the functions makes it look like you expect them to be used as globals within the functions, which is misleading. (And the same goes for `file`—you do need that defined, but not at the top.)

Then, if you abstract all the top-level stuff (including those two global variables) into a function, this takes away all possibility for confusion.

So, leave your three function definitions, then:

```
def main():
    file = ("F:/media/KINGSTON/Networking/network.txt")
    Alist = create_matrix(file)
    node = start_node(Alist)
    check_neighbours(node, Alist)
main()
```

Answer (score -1):

In function `create_matrix` when you're writing `Alist = []` you're creating a new local variable `Alist` which shadows global variable `Alist`. Try the following:

```
def create_matrix(file):
    global Alist  # Mark Alist as global variable
    with open('network.txt') as f:
        Alist = []
        for line in f:
            part = []
            for x in line.split(','):
                part.append(int(x))
            Alist.append(part)
    return Alist
```

See more in [`global` keyword documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#global).

Comment: This isn't his problem. He has an `Alist = create_matrix(file)`, which replaces the global with the value returned by this function. Also, as he says in the question, "Alist is printing fine". It's `node` that isn't working. And meanwhile, encouraging him to switch from passing and returning variables to sharing globals is not a very good design choice.